Discord.py - react to message sent as command
i have a guessing game that i am trying to have the bot react to a users message if it is incorrect. the guess command is !g or !guess followed by the actual guess. i have been trying to get it to react to guesses that are incorrect with an X emoji. everything i searched for just doesnt work and or gives me an error saying missing the ID argument, but without the ID in the 2nd line, it throws an ID is not defined error.
@client.command(aliases=["g"])
async def guess(ctx, *, arg, ID: int):
    if arg == selected_item:
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} is correct!")
        command = client.get_command('new')
        await command(ctx)
    else:
        message = ctx.fetch_message(ID)
        await ctx.message.add_reaction("\U0001F3AB")

EDIT: i swear ive tested the solution before and it just wouldnt work, but i have posted the answer below!

Please don't edit a solution into your question. Instead, scroll all the way down and post it as an answer. You can accept your own answer after 48 hours. This will help future readers to find good answers.

SOLUTION:
@client.command(aliases=["g"])
async def guess(ctx, *, arg):
    if arg == selected_item:
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} is correct!")
        command = client.get_command('new')
        await command(ctx)
    else:
        await ctx.message.add_reaction("\U0001F3AB")

